# How to make references in GitHub readme.me?

Tags: github, reference, markdown

I want to make cross-reference in my readme file on GitHub. In the end of the second paragraph I want to add link to the **about** section. How can I do that.

#### About

Curabitur suscipit sit amet turpis ut pellentesque. Duis tristique, urna nec porttitor aliquet, nulla quam sagittis eros, non eleifend lectus leo et erat. Phasellus congue tortor varius sapien tristique, a pharetra augue facilisis. Ut vitae odio purus. Vestibulum id sem turpis. Sed in ante consectetur, *eleifend* ligula sed, malesuada enim. Aliquam blandit consequat mi a hendrerit. Integer in condimentum diam. **Proin** ac elit vitae leo egestas ultricies vel eu mauris. Morbi auctor quis mi ac mattis. Aenean varius velit eu nunc euismod sodales. Aenean eu dolor vitae massa fringilla vulputate et non turpis.

#### Specification

Sed blandit tincidunt tempus. Vivamus eget consectetur est. Nulla facilisi. Proin vulputate molestie nisl, et molestie leo luctus id. Vestibulum vel pretium purus. Vestibulum vehicula lorem ac quam mollis, a posuere mi semper. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Etiam turpis quam, viverra iaculis tincidunt sed, lobortis porta felis. Ut tempus vitae lorem non vulputate. Aenean vulputate egestas facilisis. Phasellus nisl arcu, bibendum quis tincidunt eget, aliquam vitae risus. Proin lacinia fermentum mauris vel volutpat. Nulla facilisi. Proin tempus neque sed libero tincidunt tempus.

For more information see:[#About]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a common markdown link with the anchor as a link target:

```
For more information see: [About](#about)
```